How to config core in AWS API Gateway?
Im new to aws, and i have been doing some experiments, and ran into a problem.
Here's the project overview:
I have a client side, built in react, and using axios for request/response.
In the client-side, there is a form. The form will send the data to aws.
API Gateway(http api) will trigger a lambda function which will send the form data to a designated email(via ses).
I've made it work, but i dnt like the fact that i have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*".
I tried setting it to "http://localhost:3000/inquiry" or/and "http://localhost:3000/", which are my development environment, but it throws an error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/send-email' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My code so far:
// Client-side

try{
    await axios.post(
        "https://xxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/send-email",
        JSON.stringify(formData),
        {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    }

// Lambda

const { SES } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");
const ses = new SES({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });

exports.handler = async function(event) {
  try {
    if (!event || typeof event !== 'object') {
      throw new Error('Invalid input: event is not an object or is undefined');
    }

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    console.log(body);
    
    const params = {
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["xxx.xxx@gmail.com"],
      },
      Message: {
        Body: {
          Text: { Data: `
              Name: ${body.firstName} ${body.lastName}
              Email: ${body.email}
              Phone: ${body.phone}
        },
        Subject: { Data: "Test Email" },
      },
      Source: "xxx.xxx0@gmail.com",
    }
    
    const data = await ses.sendEmail(params);
    
        return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Email sent successfully", data }),
    };
  }


   catch (error) {
   return {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Error sending email", error: error.message }),
    };
  }
};

// api gateway > cors config

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
http://localhost:3000/
http://localhost:3000/inquiry

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
content-type

Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
GET
POST
OPTIONS

Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
None

I would like to know if something is wrong with my code or config, that it doenst work with "http://localhost:3000/", but works with "*" in Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Also, if there is any unnecessary code or config in the above, please feel free to correct me.
Thanks in advance!

Instead of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" for your request you can simply add the domain which you are making calls to which would be "https://xxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com" in this case. This will tell the browser to allow cross origin requests and response to only the specific domain.

Thank you for your response. I did that, but the error described above was thrown
